# How to set Ternary Operator "Loading" Div inside React Component with Two Return statements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

The API that I am using is slow. My React component is using FetchAPI and has two return statements.

I want to incorporate a ternary operator condition that will display a "Loading.." div while I wait for the data **like this**: **https://codesandbox.io/s/api-fetch-using-usestate-useeffect-k024k**

How do I include a "Loading" ternary with **two return statements** in my code below? Note: I drastically reduced my code to not drive anyone insane so I only included the overall structure. You're welcome!

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https.data.json')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ data: data}))
  }

  render() {

    let theList = this.state.map((item, id) => {

      return (
        <Card>A bunch of API Stuff </Card>
      );

    })
    return (
      <div className="search-wrap">
        <Row>
          {theList}
        </Row>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly. You want a ternary operator with more than one condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My React component is using FetchAPI and has two return statements.

No, it doesn't. It has one:

```
render() {

  let theList = this.state.map((item, id) => {

    return (
      <Card>A bunch of API Stuff </Card>
    );

  })
  return (                               // <========== here
    <div className="search-wrap">
      <Row>
        {theList}
      </Row>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The other one is a `return` within your `map` callback, which doesn't have any effect on your `render` method at all.

If you want to use the conditional operator to show a loading indicator, you'd do it in your `render`'s return:

```
render() {
  let { loading } = this.state; // *** Get the flag

  let theList = this.state.map((item, id) => {

    return (
      <Card>A bunch of API Stuff </Card>
    );

  })
  return (                          // *** Use it in the below
    <div className="search-wrap">
      <Row>
        {loading ? <p>Loading...</p> : theList}
      </Row>
    </div>
  )
}
```

You might also want to avoid the unnecessary `map` call, but if you know your state is initialized with an empty array, that call is harmless. But if you want to get rid of it:

```
render() {
  let { loading } = this.state; // *** Get the flag

  let theList = !loading && this.state.map((item, id) => {

    return (
      <Card>A bunch of API Stuff </Card>
    );

  })
  return (                          // *** Use it in the below
    <div className="search-wrap">
      <Row>
        {loading ? <p>Loading...</p> : theList}
      </Row>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I used your second solution mixed with putting loading in the constructor and API call. Thank you for clarifying about the return statement. I was just speaking in general.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a boolean field to your state which indicates that data is being loaded.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      loading: true, // this one
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https.data.json')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ data: data, loading: false }))
  }

  render() {

    if (this.state.loading)
       return <div>Loading...</div>

    let theList = this.state.map((item, id) => {

      return (
        <Card>A bunch of API Stuff </Card>
      );

    })
    return (
      <div className="search-wrap">
        <Row>
          {theList}
        </Row>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to respond! The loading in the constructor and componentDidMount was so helpful! I would upvote your answer if I could. I'm new here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your code should look like the following:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      isLoading: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true }); // mount the loading component when we will start the fecth
    fetch('https.data.json')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ data: data}))
      .then(() => this.setState({ isLoading: false })) // unmount Loading component when the fetch ends
  }

  render() {
    let theList = this.state.map((item, id) => {
      return (
        <Card>A bunch of API Stuff </Card>
      );
    })

    // Here we will return the Loading component as long as isLoading is true
    return (isLoading) ? <Loading /> : (
      <div className="search-wrap">
        <Row>
          {theList}
        </Row>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

So basically we will add a boolean variable (isLoading) that will handle the state of the fetch and we will add it into the state of the component. When the fetch is triggered, this variable will be `true` otherwise it will be `false`.

So then in the `return` statement, we can use a ternary operator based on the value of this new variable. If it is `true` we will return a Loading component or a simple `div` saying `Loading...`. Otherwise we will return the App component with the data loaded.

I hope this help :)

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to respond. I would upvote your answer if I could. Someone answered before you and it worked. Sorry, I'm just now seeing yours.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Note that you can export directly the class since the beginning. Also, you can simplify the state, without a explicit constructor.
To know the fetch state, you should add a `isLoading` condition before and after fetching the data. Then, in the render, you can return one single node, and inside render the components that you want based on your status. With this coding style, you can even show when the fetch returns an empty array.

```
export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    data: [],
    isLoading: false
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      isLoading: true
    }, () => {
      fetch('https.data.json')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({
        data,false
      }))
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      {
        this.state.isLoading &&
        <span>
          Loading...
        </span>
      }
      {
        !this.state.isLoading &&
        (this.state.data.length > 0) &&
        <div className="search-wrap">
          <Row>
            {
              this.state.data.map((item, id) => {
                return (
                  <Card key={id}>
                    A bunch of API Stuff
                  </Card>
                );
               })
            }
          </Row>
        </div>
      }
      {
        !this.state.isLoading &&
        (this.state.data.length === 0) &&
        <span>
          There's no data to show
        </span>
      }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!
Denny

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to respond. I would upvote your answer if I could. Someone answered before you and it worked. Sorry, I'm just now seeing yours.

Comment: No worries! It may be helpful for others in the future. :)